# Svn code check in to some other branch without commitng to the current branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have checked out the code from one branch. After checking out made some changes in my local code base which I have checked out.
Now i want that modified code base from my local to be checked in some other branch without committing to the current branch.
The new branch where I need to check doesn't have any code it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) for ABC-cases
2. Try to speak on SVN-lingua (!"checked in", but "commited")
3. Use `svn switch BRANCH-URL`